# Yocto Build Error

Tags: embedded-linux, busybox, yocto-project

I am building images(yocto,bitbake,busybox) for two differnt karo SOM's.  Both of the configuration files are the same (including my own software)

One build fails during the QA portion of the build process on the recipe for the Berkeley DB from Oracle. I am not even sure what is requiring this, but something does.

```
ERROR: db-6.0.30-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: db path 'work/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/db/6.0.30-r0/packages-split/db/usr/lib/libdb-6.so' [dev-so]
ERROR: db-6.0.30-r0 do_package_qa: QA run found fatal errors. Please consider fixing them.
ERROR: db-6.0.30-r0 do_package_qa: Function failed: do_package_qa
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/test/karo/fsl-community-bsp_5011/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/db/6.0.30-r0/temp/log.do_package_qa.1270
ERROR: Task 2138 (/home/test/karo/fsl-community-bsp_5011/sources/poky/meta/recipes-support/db/db_6.0.30.bb, do_package_qa) failed with exit code '1'
```

In the folder the error mentions is the .so file along with a link back to that same so file minus the minor version.

```
-rwxr-xr-x 2 test test 1.1M Apr  9 12:23 libdb-6.0.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 test test   12 Apr  9 12:24 libdb-6.so -> libdb-6.0.so
```

This linked file is being created during the build at some point (removing the linked file or even the whole build directory and rerunning results in the same issue)

I think I could probably find a way to disable the QA check, but thats not ideal since something requires this and I dont like having to disable checks for production code.

The Error log file mentioned in the error is here:

```
DEBUG: Executing python function sstate_task_prefunc
DEBUG: Python function sstate_task_prefunc finished
DEBUG: Executing python function do_package_qa
NOTE: DO PACKAGE QA
DEBUG: Executing python function read_subpackage_metadata
DEBUG: Python function read_subpackage_metadata finished
NOTE: Package db skipping QA tests: ['dev-soalready-stripped']
NOTE: Checking Package: db
NOTE: arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-objdump -p /home/test/karo/fsl-community-bsp_5011/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/db/6.0.30-r0/packages-split/db/usr/lib/libdb-6.0.so
ERROR: QA Issue: non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: db path 'work/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/db/6.0.30-r0/packages-split/db/usr/lib/libdb-6.so' [dev-so]
NOTE: Checking Package: db-bin
NOTE: arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-objdump -p /home/test/karo/fsl-community-bsp_5011/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/db/6.0.30-r0/packages-split/db-bin/usr/bin/db_stat
NOTE: arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-objdump -p /home/test/karo/fsl-community-bsp_5011/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/db/6.0.30-r0/packages-split/db-bin/usr/bin/db_deadlock
NOTE: arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-objdump -p /home/test/karo/fsl-community-bsp_5011/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/db/6.0.30-r0/packages-split/db-bin/usr/bin/db_replicate
NOTE: arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-objdump -p /home/test/karo/fsl-community-bsp_5011/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/db/6.0.30-r0/packages-split/db-bin/usr/bin/db_log_verify
NOTE: arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-objdump -p /home/test/karo/fsl-community-bsp_5011/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/db/6.0.30-r0/packages-split/db-bin/usr/bin/db_verify
NOTE: arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-objdump -p /home/test/karo/fsl-community-bsp_5011/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/db/6.0.30-r0/packages-split/db-bin/usr/bin/db_upgrade
NOTE: arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-objdump -p /home/test/karo/fsl-community-bsp_5011/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/db/6.0.30-r0/packages-split/db-bin/usr/bin/db_printlog
NOTE: arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-objdump -p /home/test/karo/fsl-community-bsp_5011/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/db/6.0.30-r0/packages-split/db-bin/usr/bin/db_archive
NOTE: arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-objdump -p /home/test/karo/fsl-community-bsp_5011/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/db/6.0.30-r0/packages-split/db-bin/usr/bin/db_hotbackup
NOTE: arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-objdump -p /home/test/karo/fsl-community-bsp_5011/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/db/6.0.30-r0/packages-split/db-bin/usr/bin/db_dump
NOTE: arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-objdump -p /home/test/karo/fsl-community-bsp_5011/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/db/6.0.30-r0/packages-split/db-bin/usr/bin/db_load
NOTE: arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-objdump -p /home/test/karo/fsl-community-bsp_5011/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/db/6.0.30-r0/packages-split/db-bin/usr/bin/db_checkpoint
NOTE: arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-objdump -p /home/test/karo/fsl-community-bsp_5011/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/db/6.0.30-r0/packages-split/db-bin/usr/bin/db_recover
NOTE: arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-objdump -p /home/test/karo/fsl-community-bsp_5011/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/db/6.0.30-r0/packages-split/db-bin/usr/bin/db_tuner
NOTE: Checking Package: db-staticdev
NOTE: Checking Package: db-dev
NOTE: Package db-cxx skipping QA tests: ['dev-so']
NOTE: Checking Package: db-cxx
NOTE: arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-objdump -p /home/test/karo/fsl-community-bsp_5011/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/db/6.0.30-r0/packages-split/db-cxx/usr/lib/libdb_cxx-6.0.so
NOTE: Checking Package: db-doc
NOTE: Checking Package: db-dbg
NOTE: arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-objdump -p /home/test/karo/fsl-community-bsp_5011/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/db/6.0.30-r0/packages-split/db-dbg/usr/bin/.debug/db_stat
NOTE: arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-objdump -p /home/test/karo/fsl-community-bsp_5011/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/db/6.0.30-r0/packages-split/db-dbg/usr/bin/.debug/db_deadlock
NOTE: arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-objdump -p /home/test/karo/fsl-community-bsp_5011/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/db/6.0.30-r0/packages-split/db-dbg/usr/bin/.debug/db_replicate
NOTE: arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-objdump -p /home/test/karo/fsl-community-bsp_5011/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/db/6.0.30-r0/packages-split/db-dbg/usr/bin/.debug/db_log_verify
NOTE: arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-objdump -p /home/test/karo/fsl-community-bsp_5011/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/db/6.0.30-r0/packages-split/db-dbg/usr/bin/.debug/db_verify
NOTE: arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-objdump -p /home/test/karo/fsl-community-bsp_5011/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/db/6.0.30-r0/packages-split/db-dbg/usr/bin/.debug/db_upgrade
NOTE: arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-objdump -p /home/test/karo/fsl-community-bsp_5011/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/db/6.0.30-r0/packages-split/db-dbg/usr/bin/.debug/db_printlog
NOTE: arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-objdump -p /home/test/karo/fsl-community-bsp_5011/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/db/6.0.30-r0/packages-split/db-dbg/usr/bin/.debug/db_archive
NOTE: arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-objdump -p /home/test/karo/fsl-community-bsp_5011/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/db/6.0.30-r0/packages-split/db-dbg/usr/bin/.debug/db_hotbackup
NOTE: arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-objdump -p /home/test/karo/fsl-community-bsp_5011/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/db/6.0.30-r0/packages-split/db-dbg/usr/bin/.debug/db_dump
NOTE: arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-objdump -p /home/test/karo/fsl-community-bsp_5011/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/db/6.0.30-r0/packages-split/db-dbg/usr/bin/.debug/db_load
NOTE: arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-objdump -p /home/test/karo/fsl-community-bsp_5011/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/db/6.0.30-r0/packages-split/db-dbg/usr/bin/.debug/db_checkpoint
NOTE: arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-objdump -p /home/test/karo/fsl-community-bsp_5011/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/db/6.0.30-r0/packages-split/db-dbg/usr/bin/.debug/db_recover
NOTE: arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-objdump -p /home/test/karo/fsl-community-bsp_5011/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/db/6.0.30-r0/packages-split/db-dbg/usr/bin/.debug/db_tuner
NOTE: arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-objdump -p /home/test/karo/fsl-community-bsp_5011/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/db/6.0.30-r0/packages-split/db-dbg/usr/lib/.debug/libdb_cxx-6.0.so
NOTE: arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-objdump -p /home/test/karo/fsl-community-bsp_5011/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/db/6.0.30-r0/packages-split/db-dbg/usr/lib/.debug/libdb-6.0.so
NOTE: Checking Package: db-locale
ERROR: QA run found fatal errors. Please consider fixing them.
DEBUG: Python function do_package_qa finished
ERROR: Function failed: do_package_qa
```

And the busy box recipe is below(not written by me). There is some mention in there about dev so files, but Im not sure if that might be the issue or even what changes might need to be made then.

```
# Version 6 of the Berkeley DB from Oracle (formerly Sleepycat)
#
# At present this package only installs the DB code
# itself (shared libraries, .a in the dev package),
# documentation and headers.
#
# The headers have the same names as those as v3
# of the DB, only one version can be used *for dev*
# at once - DB3 and DB6 can both be installed on the
# same system at the same time if really necessary.
SECTION = "libs"
SUMMARY = "Berkeley Database v6"
HOMEPAGE = "http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/berkeleydb/overview/index.html"
LICENSE = "AGPL-3.0"
VIRTUAL_NAME ?= "virtual/db"
RCONFLICTS_${PN} = "db3"

# Note, when upgraded to 6.1.x, a patch in RPM will need to be removed to activate db 6.1 support.

SRC_URI = "http://download.oracle.com/berkeley-db/db-${PV}.tar.gz"
SRC_URI += "file://arm-thumb-mutex_db5.patch;patchdir=.. \
            file://fix-parallel-build.patch \
            file://Makefile-let-libso_target-depend-on-bt_rec.patch \
            file://Makefile-let-libdb-6.0.la-depend-os_map.l.patch;patchdir=.. \
           "

SRC_URI[md5sum] = "ad28eb86ad3203b5422844db179c585b"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "608e4b1cf390e9bf54c0ef00c5bd9ca76d36e2261b9f4d33d54516f3f6a20fd2"

# Exclude NC versions which lack AES encryption
UPSTREAM_CHECK_REGEX = "db-(?P<pver>\d+\.\d+(\.\d+)?).tar"
UPSTREAM_CHECK_URI = "http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/berkeleydb/downloads/index-082944.html"

LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://../LICENSE;md5=1ec8b0b17cc31513fe35ab10716f8490"

inherit autotools

# Put virtual/db in any appropriate provider of a
# relational database, use it as a dependency in
# place of a specific db and use:
#
# PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/db
#
# to select the correct db in the build (distro) .conf
PROVIDES += "${VIRTUAL_NAME}"

# bitbake isn't quite clever enough to deal with sleepycat,
# the distribution sits in the expected directory, but all
# the builds must occur from a sub-directory.  The following
# persuades bitbake to go to the right place
S = "${WORKDIR}/db-${PV}/dist"
B = "${WORKDIR}/db-${PV}/build_unix"
SPDX_S = "${WORKDIR}/db-${PV}"

# The executables go in a separate package - typically there
# is no need to install these unless doing real database
# management on the system.
inherit lib_package

PACKAGES =+ "${PN}-cxx"
FILES_${PN}-cxx = "${libdir}/*cxx*so"


# The dev package has the .so link (as in db3) and the .a's -
# it is therefore incompatible (cannot be installed at the
# same time) as the db3 package
# sort out the .so since they do version prior to the .so
SOLIBS = "-6*.so"
FILES_SOLIBSDEV = "${libdir}/libdb.so ${libdir}/libdb_cxx.so"

#configuration - set in local.conf to override
# All the --disable-* options replace --enable-smallbuild, which breaks a bunch of stuff (eg. postfix)
DB6_CONFIG ?= "--enable-o_direct --disable-cryptography --disable-queue --disable-replication --disable-verify --disable-compat185 --disable-sql"

EXTRA_OECONF = "${DB6_CONFIG} --enable-shared --enable-cxx --with-sysroot"

# Override the MUTEX setting here, the POSIX library is
# the default - "POSIX/pthreads/library".
# Don't ignore the nice SWP instruction on the ARM:
# These enable the ARM assembler mutex code
ARM_MUTEX = "--with-mutex=ARM/gcc-assembly"
MUTEX = ""
MUTEX_arm = "${ARM_MUTEX}"
MUTEX_armeb = "${ARM_MUTEX}"
EXTRA_OECONF += "${MUTEX}"
EXTRA_OEMAKE_class-target = "LIBTOOL=${STAGING_BINDIR_CROSS}/${HOST_SYS}-libtool"

# Cancel the site stuff - it's set for db3 and destroys the
# configure.
CONFIG_SITE = ""
do_configure() {
    gnu-configize --force ${S}
    export STRIP="true"
    oe_runconf
}

do_compile_prepend() {
    sed -i -e 's|hardcode_into_libs=yes|hardcode_into_libs=no|' \
        ${B}/libtool
}

do_install_append() {
    mkdir -p ${D}/${includedir}/db60
    mv ${D}/${includedir}/db.h ${D}/${includedir}/db60/.
    mv ${D}/${includedir}/db_cxx.h ${D}/${includedir}/db60/.
    ln -s db60/db.h ${D}/${includedir}/db.h
    ln -s db60/db_cxx.h ${D}/${includedir}/db_cxx.h

    # The docs end up in /usr/docs - not right.
    if test -d "${D}/${prefix}/docs"
    then
        mkdir -p "${D}/${datadir}"
        test ! -d "${D}/${docdir}" || rm -rf "${D}/${docdir}"
        mv "${D}/${prefix}/docs" "${D}/${docdir}"
    fi

    chown -R root:root ${D}
}

INSANE_SKIP_${PN} = "dev-so"
INSANE_SKIP_${PN}-cxx = "dev-so"

BBCLASSEXTEND = "native nativesdk"
```